# How to get string value from another class using selenium and testng in java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I am trying to get the value of string in the first class and use it to another class. Below is my code :

```
public class Add extends driver {
    public static String reportV1;

    @Test
    public String export() throws InterruptedException, IOException {


// Report Name
        WebElement report1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#nReportName")));
        reportV1 = report1.getAttribute("value");
        if (reportV1.equals(reportV)) {
            System.out.println(" PASSED - Report Name: " + reportV1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" FAILED - Report Name: " + reportV1);
            soft.assertTrue(false);
        }
soft.assertAll();
return reportV1;
```

I'm new to java, so can someone help me to get the value of string?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read about static fields first to get clear picture about this thing.
Anyway, static variables can be accessed by calling with the class name **ClassName.VariableName.**

*Add.reportV1* in your case. Btw in your example *reportV1* is not initialized yet, fyi.